# Why this code produces warning: Use of uninitialized value

Tags: perl, soaplite

This code:

```
my $url = 'http://172.27.1.250:8080/X/services/XSOAP';
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( 
    service=> 'http://172.27.1.250:8080/X/services/XSOAP?wsdl', 
    proxy => $url
);
$soap->autotype(0)->readable(1);
$soap->ns('http://www.example.org/X/');

my $som =  $soap->call('serviceX', 
           SOAP::Data->name('serviceXRequest')->value($value));
```

Generates following warning

> Use of uninitialized value $ns in string eq at /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3396.

What should I do get rid of it without supressing warnings?

Comment: What version of SOAP::Lite are you running?

Comment: Can you put breakpoint or a print-statement after the `SOAP::Lite-> new(...);`? I'd like to know if this warning happens at contruction of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because SOAP::Lite is expecting the $ns variable (an XML namespace identifier) to have a value, which you have not set.

Your best course of action is to look at line 3396 and see what is going on there.

Maybe it's a bug in your version SOAP::Lite.  Have you check the RT queue for the module?